# Reusable child components with mobx store, should I reference the parent store to the child?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm building a React widget which has a parent component and two children, each have it's own store.

```
<Parent>
  <ChildA />
  <ChildB />
</Parent>
```

I need the child components to be reusable. 
However, both the children stores have some observable/computed variables they needs from the parent store.
Should I pass the parent store to the children?

```
parentStore = new ParentStore();
childStore = new ChildStore(parentStore);
```

I'm not sure if it's the best practice. Doesn't it mean that every other Parent that will call this child component will have to hold the same exact variable names?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there're two popular ways to share state between stores.

One of them you have already shown: passing one store as parameter to the other one.

The second approach (and the best in my opinion) is to set a "rootStore" that will hold a common scope for the rest of the stores:

```
class RootStore {
    constructor() {
        this.userStore = new UserStore(this);
        this.todoStore = new TodoStore(this);
    }
}

class UserStore {
    constructor(rootStore) {
        this.rootStore = rootStore
    }

    getTodos(user) {
        return this.rootStore.todoStore.todos.filter(todo => todo.author === user)
    }
}

class TodoStore {
    @observable todos = []

    constructor(rootStore) {
        this.rootStore = rootStore
    }
}
```

In this way you can keep all stores linked.

On the other hand you said that your component need to be reusable, if that's the case maybe you shouldn't keep it attached to the store directly, why not pass that data using props?